# TPM FAPI sealing data inside /dev

Tags: tpm, configuration

I am using TPM simulator in my local VM to test FAPI API and am able to seal the important data  inside directory `~/.local/share/tpm2-tss/user/keystore` as per the path mentioned in config file `/etc/fapi-config.json`

```
"profile_dir": "/usr/local/etc/tpm2-tss/fapi-profiles/",
"user_dir": "~/.local/share/tpm2-tss/user/keystore",
"tcti": "",
"ek_cert_less" : "yes"
```

After some trial runs, I will play with hardware TPM where `/dev/tpm0` will be available.

When we do that, do we need to change the `"user_dir": "~/.local/share/tpm2-tss/user/keystore"` to `"user_dir": "/dev/tpm0"` in `/etc/fapi-config.json` to store the sealed json metadata or how we will use FAPI API with regard to `/dev/tpm0`? How will this directory be used?